# How to open a PWA on macOS without opening the browser?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, youtube, brave, progressive-web-app

I installed the [YouTube music PWA](https://music.youtube.com) via Brave Browser (it should be the same on chrome) on macOS (running Big Sur).

My problem is that when I launch the app it also opens the browser with it, I would like to just open the app.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible.  What I have done instead is use [nativefier](https://github.com/nativefier/nativefier#readme) to create a single site browser that points to the PWA's URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for!